# Python multiprocessing task queue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I'm experimenting with the multiprocessing module and I'm getting some strange behavior. I have a list of tasks, which I first enqueue to a task_queue. Then I start all processes, which have access to both the task queue and the result queue. After the processes have started, I actively check for new content in the result queue while there are active processes.
The weird behavior is that when I start the script below, 4 of the processes exit immediately, and all the work is done by one process. No `except Exception` clauses are entered.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
from time import sleep, time
from queue import Empty

def function_doing_heavy_computation(task):
    return task + 1

def service_function(func, tasks_q, result_q):
    """
    :param func: user passed function that takes one argument - the task and returns the result of processing the task 
    :param tasks_q: 
    :param result_q: 
    """
    while True:
        try:
            task = tasks_q.get_nowait()
        except Empty:
            result_q.close()  # https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue.close
            result_q.join_thread()
            print("Worker finished ")
            break
        except Exception as ex:
            print(str(ex))

        try:
            res = func(task)
        except Exception as ex:
            print(str(ex))

        result_q.put_nowait(res)


def multiproc(func, all_tasks, num_procs):
    result = []

    task_queue, result_queue = Queue(), Queue()
    # add the tasks to the task queue
    start_put_tasks = time()
    for x in all_tasks:
        task_queue.put_nowait(x)
    print("Finished adding tasks in %.2f" % (time() - start_put_tasks))
    # create the processes and pass them the task and result queue
    start_create_procs = time()
    procs = []
    for _ in range(num_procs):
        p = Process(target=service_function, args=(func, task_queue, result_queue))
        procs.append(p)
    for p in procs:
        p.start()

    print("Started %i workers in %.2f" % (len(procs), time() - start_create_procs))

    # collect the results in a list, and return it
    start_drain_queue = time()
    liveprocs = list(procs)
    while liveprocs:
        # drain the current contents of the result_queue
        while True:
            try:
                result.append(result_queue.get_nowait())
            except Empty:
                break
        # set the currently active procs. while loop will exit if all procs have terminated
        liveprocs = [p for p in procs if p.is_alive()]
        # no process has put a result/all ready results have been drained. wait for new results to arrive
        sleep(.1)

    print("Finished draining result queue in %.2f" % (time() - start_drain_queue))
    if len(result) != len(all_tasks):
        raise RuntimeError("Only %i/%i tasks processed" % (len(result), len(all_tasks)))
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    start = time()
    # a task is just a number here.
    # normally more tasks than workers. i
    tasks = range(100000)

    result = multiproc(func=function_doing_heavy_computation, all_tasks=tasks, num_procs=5)
    print("Done in %s seconds" % str(time() - start))
    assert len(tasks) == len(result)
    print("Processed %i tasks" % len(result))
```

Comment: It just ends too quickly. Try a heavier function.

Comment: Also, try the ProcessPoolExecutor: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor

Comment: @LiranFunaro thanks for the response. Note that the function that operates on a single task is not `service_function`, but the `func` passed to it. Even so, the same behavior is observed even for 10 000 000 "tasks"

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion for the ProcessPoolExecutor. I am aware of the [map()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map), part of `Pool`, but I wanted to understand better how the more primitive components behave.